# How to have MapHttpAttributeRoutes register parent class routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a case where I'm trying to create a whole bunch of Api controllers.  I have created a base class controller that has all the basic GET, PUT, POST, DELETE actions as well as a few others that seem common for the project.

I then use T4 to script out each table in my db (the EF context, but none the less) as a controller, obviously inheriting from that parent controller (who ultimate inherits from ApiController.  It all works great except for some routing issues.

Apparently you cannot define attributed routes in the base class and have the MapHttpAttributeRoutes find them.

Given this suedo code below is there any suggestion contrary to this belief and is there a "good" way to handle this?  For now the thought is to ditch the base class and script each controller out in T4.

```
public class TestBaseController: ApiController {

    // GET api/user
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}


[RoutePrefix("apiv2/user")]
public class UserController:  TestBaseController
{
    [Route("type")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetType()
    {
        return "my test type";
    } ...
```

apiv2/user/ results in a 404, but apiv2/user/type returns the expected string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default attribute routes are not inherited, however with Web Api 2.2, we added an ability to do that:

Example:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Success:" + id;
    }
}
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
}

//---------------------------------------------------

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());

public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> 
    GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>
        (inherit: true);
    }
}
```